# vertica check if unique elements for each group from two columns are identical

Tags: sql, comparison, unique, vertica

Table in vertica:

```
gid          a       b    
1            2       2    
1            3       2    
1            1       1    
2            2       1    
2            1       2
2            1       1    
3            1       1    
3            2       1
```

Note, the values in the two columns are not distinct for a given gid (see gid=2)
For each gid, I want to check if the unique elements in col a is the same as the unique elements in col b, if equal, status = 1 else 0. The expected result would be:

```
gid     status

1        0    
2        1
3        0
```

How to achieve this in vertica or sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the values in the two columns are distinct for a given `gid`, you can do this with a `full outer join` and `group by`:

```
select coalesce(t.gid, t2.gid) as gid,
       (case when count(t.gid) = count(*) and count(t2.gid) = count(*)
             then 1
             else 0
        end)
from invertica t full outer join
     invertica t2
     on t.gid = t2.gid and t.a = t2.b
group by coalesce(t.gid, t2.gid);
```

If the values are not distinct, you would need to clarify your question to specify whether the counts need to be the same in each column.  (If you don't care about the counts, the above will work.)

EDIT:

You could also express this using `not exists`:

```
select t.gid, max(val)
from (select t.gid,
             (case when not exists (select 1 from invertica t2 where t.gid = t2.gid and t.a = t2.b)
                   then 0
                   when not exists (select 1 from invertica t2 where t.gid = t2.gid and t.b = t2.a)
                   then 0
                   else 1
              end) as val
      from invertica t
     ) t
group by t.gid;
```

Comment: The values in the two columns are not distinct for a given gid, I will update the OP

Comment: @tonystarkix . . . That is obvious, actually, once I stared at the data a bit more.  Both solution work if you care about the *sets* of values.  If you care about the counts, slightly more needs to be done.